# Aggregate values at hourly interval using SQL server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have below test data in the table

```
ID  TEST_DATE          Value
1   10/21/2019 0:00     10
1   10/21/2019 0:15     10
1   10/21/2019 0:30     10
1   10/21/2019 0:45     10
1   10/21/2019 1:00     20
1   10/21/2019 1:15     10
1   10/21/2019 1:30     10
1   10/21/2019 1:45     10
1   10/21/2019 2:00     30
```

I have written below SQL query to aggregate the values at hourly interval

```
SELECT ID, dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, TEST_DATE), 0) as ACTUAL_DATE,SUM(VALUE) as ACTUAL_VALUE 
FROM TEST_TABLE
GROUP BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, TEST_DATE), 0) ,ID
```

currently getting results as

```
ID   ACTUAL_DATE       ACTUAL_VALUE
1    10/21/2019 0:00    40
1    10/21/2019 1:00    50
```

**What should be my SQL query , If i want the hourly aggregation to consider from 15th minute instead of 0th minute .**

Like first hour should have aggregation of

```
2019-10-21 00:15:00 - 10
2019-10-21 00:30:00 - 10
2019-10-21 00:45:00 - 10
2019-10-21 01:00:00 - 20
```

**And the results should look like**

```
ID   ACTUAL_DATE       ACTUAL_VALUE
1    10/21/2019 0:00    50
1    10/21/2019 1:00    60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following expression will map the dates such as `2019-10-21 00:15`, `2019-10-21 00:30`, `2019-10-21 00:45` and `2019-10-21 01:00` to `2019-10-21 00:15`:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, TEST_DATE) - 15) / 60 * 60 + 15, 0) AS ACTUAL_DATE
```

Use this expression in your `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract 15 minutes:

```
SELECT t.ID, v.ACTUAL_DATE, SUM(t.VALUE) as ACTUAL_VALUE 
FROM TEST_TABLE T CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (DATEADD(HOUR,
                      DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, t.TEST_DATE)),
                      0
                     )
             )
     ) v(ACTUAL_DATE)
GROUP BY t.ID, v.ACTUAL_DATE;
```